# Pick rows above a row that meets a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this. I want to pick the rows above if a certain condition is met. For example here if number > 2, then i want to pick the rows with John, richard and paul. i.e the rows with numbers that led up to three. I also want to pick the 5 rows above myers. i.e myers, Jessica, Ashton, Whiley, Jason.

```
   name     number
   Adrian     1
   Peter      2
   John       1  
   Richard    2
   Paul       3 
   Ashley     1
   Winchester 0
   Jason      1
   Whiley     2 
   Ashton     3
   Jessica    4
   myers      5
```

The output could look like this

```
 name    number
 John       1
 Richard    2
 Paul       3
 Jason      1
 Whiley     2 
 Ashton     3
 Jessica    4
 myers      5
```

Comment: could you elaborate exactly how your output might look?

Comment: @CodeGeek123 okay, and the number>2 that you are saying, is static or dynamic? i mean as per you define your condition the result should change?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example number can be > 3 or 4 etc. The results should change accordingly

Comment: @CodeGeek123 Check the answer deepika :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This awkwardly works:

```
def get_number(n):
    position = df[df['number']==n].index[0]
    find = range(position - (n-1), position + 1)
    return df.loc[find]

print get_number(3)
```

Comment: Thanks Zipa. One question though for data sets that done contain the condition I get an index error on line 2 : IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Answer (score 0):

```
def Select_no(n):
    position = df[df['number']==n].index[0]
    find = range(position - (n-1), position + 1)
    return df.loc[find]

df1 = Select_no(3)
df2 = df[7:]
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

you could also do `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`, if you want your index to be starting from 0.
[image]

Comment: Did you seriously copy my answer?